# Properties in Angular2 Alpha 44

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass data from my parent component to my child components,

it seems that it changed from older version or i don't see what i'm doing wrong!

```
players = Array<PlayerModel>
```

here is the code:

```
<best-score-board [players]="players"></best-score-board>
```

in the bestScoreBoardComponent

```
import {Component, Input, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {PlayerModel} from '../../models/players/player.ts';

@Component({
    selector: 'best-score-board',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/leaderboards/bestScoreBoard.html',
    directives: [NgFor],
    properties: [players]
})
export class BestScoreBoardComponent {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

there is no error... but the app is not loading at all...

seeing   loading...   (from my main app selector loading...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Angular Alpha.38, properties are renamed to `inputs`. See this changeset https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/adbfd29

Comment: Got it to work thx a lot,  @Input() players;  over my constructor did work